# Make selection follow focus in UWP ListView

Tags: uwp

I am trying to make ListView with single selection to make selection instantly follow keyboard focus.

I am looking at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview#item-selection-and-interaction

However, the only similar documented mode is when focus is moved between elements with keyboard, but to select focused item user needs to hit one more key.

Is there an easy way to make keyboard move both focus and selection.

Comment: So you want to use the **Tab** key to navigate and select a listview item?

Comment: @JustinXL No, I want, once ListView is focused, selection to change when I press arrow keys. In the docs only item focus is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` contains a property called [`SingleSelectionFollowsFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ListViewBase_SingleSelectionFollowsFocus) which when set to `true` will select the focused item automatically when used with keyboard.

Comment: For some reason that did not work for me when my list had grouping enabled. However, it is a valid answer for normal cases.

Answer (score 1):

@AVK's answer is valid for common case. However, instead I had to `GotFocus="OnCommandGotFocus"`, probably because my list was grouped.

```cs
void OnCommandGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  if (e.OriginalSource is ListViewItem command) {
    command.IsSelected = true;
  }
}
```